# startTime is not defined at onload JavaScript Asp.net core

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core

tengo un error en un codigo JavaScript, en un sitio web Asp.net core.

Necesito hacer un Timer que me retorne a la vista principal del Proyecto.

Tengo el siguiente codigo con el que llamo a una funcion Java Script desde el evento onload de mi sitio.
Pero no me funciona, en la consola me indica que no esta definida,
pero aparentemente tengo todo correcto,
alquien me puede ayudar indicando si me falta algo en el codigo.

```
<body class="container"  onload="delayRedirect()">

<div id="delayMsg"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function delayRedirect() {
            document.getElementById('delayMsg').innerHTML = 'Please wait you'll be redirected after < span id = "countDown" > 5 < /span> seconds....';
            var count = 5;
            setInterval(function () {
                count--;
                document.getElementById('countDown').innerHTML = count;
                if (count == 0) {
                    //alert('tiempo terminado');
                    location.href = '/Adm/Capture';
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    </script>
```

error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: startTime is not defined
at onload (Capture:252:152)

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: El único error que veo es en `'Please wait you'll ` donde despues del `you` cierras la comilla, entonces debes reemplazar por comillas dobles para no tener ese problema `document.getElementById('delayMsg').innerHTML = "Please wait you'll be redirected after <span id = "countDown"> 5 </span> seconds...."`

Comment: Hola Yussef, corregí ese error pero igual no se ejecuta la función, sigue saliendo Error de Referencia en la consola. Le tengo puesto un Alert pero ni siquiera entra a la función.

Comment: Yo lo probé y funciona

Comment: Hola Yussef, ya funciona, en mi html tenía como texto el elemento countDown, le activé y ahí me funcionó perfecto. Muchas gracias

Comment: y en el id le puse asi: id = " + countDown + "